# Create Jenkins Docker Image with pre configured jobs

Tags: docker, jenkins, pipeline

I have created a bunch of Local deployment pipeline jobs, these jobs do things like remove an existing container, build a service locally, build a docker image, run the container - etc. These are not CI/CD jobs, just small pipelines for deploying locally during dev.

What I want to do now is make this available to all our devs, so they can just simply spin up a local instance of jenkins that already contains the jobs.

My docker file is reasonably straight forward...

```
FROM jenkins:latest

USER root

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo

RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# Docker
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get dist-upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates -y
RUN sh -c "echo deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-cache policy docker-engine
RUN apt-get install docker-engine -y

# .NET Core CLI dependencies
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://llvm.org/apt/jessie/ llvm-toolchain-jessie-3.6 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm.list \
    && wget -q -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        clang-3.5 \
        libc6 \
        libcurl3 \
        libgcc1 \
        libicu52 \
        liblldb-3.6 \
        liblttng-ust0 \
        libssl1.0.0 \
        libstdc++6 \
        libtinfo5 \
        libunwind8 \
        libuuid1 \
        zlib1g \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#DotNetCore
RUN curl -sSL -o dotnet.tar.gz https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=847105
RUN mkdir -p /opt/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet
RUN ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin

# Minimal Jenkins Plugins
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh git matrix-auth workflow-aggregator docker-workflow blueocean credentials-binding

# Skip initial setup
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false

COPY LocallyDeployIdentityConfig.xml /var/jenkins_home/jobs/identity/config.xml

USER jenkins
```

What I thought I could do is simply copy a job config file into the /jobs/jobname folder and the job would appear, but not only does this not appear, but now I cannot manually create jobs either. I now get a java.io.IOException "No such file or directory" - Note when I exec into the running container, the job and jobname directories exist and my config file is in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who is interested - I found a better solution. I simply map the jobs folder to a folder on my host, that way I can put the created jobs into source control and edit then add them without having to build a new docker image.

Sorted.

Comment: can you please provide a bit more details bout this approach

Answer (score 7):

Jobs need to bootstrapped while the Jenkins starts can be copied to **/usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/** folder.

But keep in mind that if the jobs(or any) already exist in Jenkins home folder, updates from **/usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/** folder won't have any effect unless you end the files with ***.override** name. 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/jenkins-support#L110

**Dockerfile**

```
# First time building of jenkins with the preconfigured job
COPY job_name/config.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/job_name/config.xml

# But if jobs need to be updated, suffix the file names with '.override'.
COPY job_name/config.xml.override /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/job_name/config.xml.override
```

Answer (score 2):

I maintain the jobs in a bootstrap folder together with configs etc.

To add a job (i.e. seedjob) I need to add the following to the `Dockerfile`:

```
# copy seedjob
COPY bootstrap/seedjob.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/seedjob/config.xml
```